# Is the question even correct?

Tags: logic, coding-theory

I have this mental ability question where I am not getting the proper pattern:

If in a certain code language 'SOLDIER' is written as 'SFJDKNR' then how will 'GENIOUS' be written in that code language?
TVPIMDF is the answer but why?

Please explain the same

Comment: That seems arbitrary.  From the first example it appears that $S,D,R$ are mapped to themselves but that is inconsistent with your answer.  So, fine...it's not a simple substitution.  But in that case I wouldn't think we'd have any where near enough information to crack the code.

Comment: Is there any other information given (e.g., the type of code/cipher) being used?

Comment: @paw88789 No sir =_=

Comment: @lulu Sir, the answer was given in the book but I didn't understand the logic.

Comment: Then I tend to agree with lulu that there is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: I'm sure we could come up with some way to justify the answer.  But, then, I expect we could justify any answer at all.

Comment: @lulu The position of S,I and R seem to be the same in the given code Language, but it has no connection with the answer but just the position of is in same Order in the answer =_=

Comment: Since we don't know anything about the code language, anything is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idea is to reverse the letter order, then move up the first three letters by one in the alphabet, move down the last three by one, and keep the middle letter fixed. At least, I think this is the answer the person who originally posed the problem was looking for.

Comment: Oh yes, I got this! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Nice one. I just hope they never have to encode <6 letters words.